# What’s this piece of vinyl siding called?

Tags: vinyl-siding

I’m trying to replace this corner piece. The vinyl was installed over the old aluminum years ago. And yes the caulking needs redone.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The broken vertical piece is called J-channel.

Note that J-channel is installed before the horizontal siding, which covers the nail holes. You’ll have to finesse replacement. Since it’s broken anyway, I’d cut more away so you can pry up the nails *slightly.* If you do that, you might be able to disengage the broken j-channel and then hook the replacement over the existing nails. A siding removal tool, which is an inexpensive tool to unhook the bottom edge of the siding from the piece below, will help you separate/unlock  the horizontal pieces to get to the nails.